# Where to write Access-Control-Allow-Origin: or Origin

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

May be this is a dumb question, but I can't find any solution regarding this.
I'm working on a cross domain matter. So I came to know by searching that I need to set my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` or `Origin` tags. But where?? Suggestions were to use these in header.

I can't see find anything that explained this. Can anyone please tell me where to put this tags and how!!

In `head` tag? or in `DOCTYPE` ? Please help...... Do I need to use JavaScript or anything?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is put your code in server side:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");// To allow all domains
```

To limit access to specific domains only:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```

I have used above code in java servlets, you can use similar methods if you are using different language.

Answer (score 0):

This should passed as an http header, that rides along with the HTTP protocol.  Your client makes a request to the the server, which looks something like this:

GET /cors HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://api.bob.com
Host: api.alice.com
Accept-Language: en-US
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0...

In your response, your server side code must *manually* add http headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  A lot of times, people will simple do something like:

response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

However, if you need to do any sort of authentication, keep in mind that if you are sending credentials (either by using a Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in your request, or setting withCredentials in your jQuery ajax call), then you have to specific the origin to be allowed in the response header:

response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://api.bob.com");

Also, be sure to handle pre-flight OPTIONS requests.

If that doesn't help, this site covers almost every scenario: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/